# some files are missing from the server adobe muse error

Tags: html, css, adobe, muse

I had no time on my hands and had to finish up a project real quick so i took the easy way out, and obviously now have a problem.. 
So, the issue is when i export from Muse(2015.1) to the FTP server my css gets messed up a bit and on the right of the website there is blank white space. So i can fix the issue by adding:
html,body

```
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

but the thing is that when i do so i start getting an error message that ""Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect." when i try to access the website. I searched around and the solution was to remove a part of the code in my HTML, but when i do that the who page doesn't load. Anyone has any idea of what could help?

Much appreciated!

Comment: EDIT: Resolved it by exporting as HTML and not uploading directly to the FTP.